# Countries with no visa requirements on its visitors

Tags: visas, countries, visa-free-entry

Recently I learnt that [Andorra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andorra) has [no visa restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Andorra) to its visitors (citizens of any country) and free to enter if they hold a passport or EU national identity card.

Are there any other country(ies) which have similar no visa restrictions for its visitors irrespective of citizenship?

PS: Though Andorra has not restrictions, one needs to have a multiple-entry Schengen visa, as it's a land-locked country and only be accessed via Spain or France.

Comment: Andorra is de-facto covered by the Schengen visa. You can't get there without passing France or Spain, so they can afford themselves not to bother. Monaco (which has its own sea access) uses French visas.

Comment: Yes, read that in the wiki page.

Comment: @dda, I rolled back the edit as you introduced an error while you did not introduce much of an improvement. Please do restrict your edits to where you can make a real difference.

Answer (score 10):

The first country that comes to mind is the Republic of the Maldives. Indeed according to this [link](http://www.themaldives.com/travel/visa-requirements.html) no visa is required. I expect this to be the case for most "paradise-like" destinations.

If a visa is needed, the best chance to enter visa-free is if you are a Scandinavian, since most countries allow Finns, Swedes and Danes to enter without a visa (source: [Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/dailychart/2011/08/visa-free-travel)).

Comment: Note that you need a visa to visit islands outside the capital in Maldives.

Answer (score 7):

Vatican city doesn't require a visa to visit its public area, mainly piazza and basilica di San Pietro, and cappella sistina.

Entering its private areas is another story though.

Like for Andorra, you still need a Schengen visa to get to Rome.

Comment: Same for San Marino.

Comment: According to Wikipedia™ there were recorded occasions of visiting Vatican without a Shengen visa, quite straightforward, one only needs to arrange for a helicopter transportation from one of Rome's airports international zone directly to Vatican. <_<

Answer (score 4):

See [VisaHQ's page on this](http://www.visahq.com/citizens/).  Select your citizenship, and it will indicate the visa requirements (or lack thereof) for each country.

Comment: I checked that website and it says I need VISA for Philippines, which I don't if I stay less than 21 days.. (I'm Spanish).

Comment: @SERPRO See http://philippines.visahq.com/requirements/Spain/ .  You are correct, but the chart does not know how long you are planning on staying, so it is presenting you with at "worst-case scenario".

Comment: @user82 it would be quite hard to find a country where you could stay for five years without any additional arrangements, other than one of your home countries, so their worst-case is a bit too worst. >_>

Answer (score 4):

Although governed by Norway, there are no restrictions for foreigners to enter, reside or work on Svalbard. As with most other examples here, the only practical way (except for chartered boats or flights) to get there is through Norway, for which you may need a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2):

Bahamas, Seychelles.. i have been to both and they require no visa before one can make entry.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Travel.SE. Please, add some official information to your answer, or it will be converted to a comment as not an answer.