# Organizing an international high school reunion and looking for a visa-friendly, enjoyable, and affordable destination

Tags: visas, international-travel, safety

I'm looking for your insights regarding organising a high school reunion in summer 2017. The number of attendees will be between 30 and 300 and they will travel/have passports from all around the world, including developing regions. **The ideal location would be safe, visa-friendly, affordable, and have an enjoyable climate in August 2017.**

The discussion following a SE Travel question [Visa-friendly country for an international conference?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/visa-friendly-country-for-an-international-conference) seems to suggest Singapore, Hong Kong, Netherlands, and Dubai as top choices for organising an international conference. I wanted to see whether you'd vouch for these suggestions for a reunion in August 2017, or propose another destination considering that we're aiming to keep attendance costs low.

Comment: Do you appreciate irony?  The question you linked to was applauded as a great question and yours faces closure for being off topic.  Virtually the same question...

Comment: How is this any different from the linked question? Isn't a school reunion a sub-type of a conference?

Comment: @GayotFow not ironic, as seen many times before, the site has evolved from 2012 when it was still in beta, and some stuff is no longer on topic.

Comment: @JonathanReez the linked one was trying to find a place for attendees from every continent, while this question is not, I guess?

Comment: @MarkMayo, yes, the mood has evolved.  Also more people cleared the voting hurdle. But it's not written anywhere that those early questions are now OT :)

Comment: @GayotFow and others, considering that we're aiming to keep attendance costs low, I wanted to see whether you'd vouch for the suggestions arising from the former question also for a reunion in August 2017, or propose another destination. Perhaps I wasn't clear, but the ideal location would be safe, visa-friendly, affordable, and have an enjoyable climate in August 2017 (These are our perimeters rather than only looking for a visa-friendly country and thus I don't think the former question is "virtually the same question". Conferences tend to be very high profile and reunions less so.)

Comment: @Sannita, August in Saint Petersburg you have the lifted bridges and white nights. Visa friendly, and as safe as any other locale. But that's an OPINION.  I can't vote to reopen your question, sorry :(

Comment: Note that Dubai is not safe or visa friendly for Israelis

Comment: Dubai in August also fails to meet the "enjoyable climate" requirement, unless you enjoy temperatures over 40C / 100F.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not a seer and cannot predict the exact situation in 2017, my vote would be for **Georgia**. Let's take a look at your criteria:

- Safe

Georgia is generally an extremely safe country, despite all the international attention towards the conflict with Russia. It's ranked at #112 in the [list of countries by intentional homicide rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_intentional_homicide_rate) and most travelers would confirm it's not a dangerous place.

- Visa-friendly

Citizens of [almost every country in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Georgia) can visit Georgia visa free or get an E-Visa online.

- Affordable to get to

Georgia's airports welcome dozens of regular and low-budget airlines, including regular flights to the hubs in Istanbul and Dubai. On average, it shouldn't be more expensive for your guests to get there.

- Affordable to stay at

[Tbilisi is cheaper than Bangkok](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=Thailand&country2=Georgia&city1=Bangkok&city2=Tbilisi&tracking=getDispatchComparison) and definitely cheaper than any other European country.

- Enjoyable climate in August

It's very hot in the capital, sunny and warm on the seaside, and sunny and cool in the mountains. You can host your event in three different sub-climates within the same country!

Answer (score -2):

A few options:

1. Asia: Honk Kong or Singapore: very safe, visa friendly, more on the expensive side, hot as hell in August, to do: mostly urban: shopping/some culture
2. Asia: Bangkok: reasonably safe, visa friendly, much cheaper than HKG or SIN (but also less clean), hot as hell in August, to do: lots of shopping/food/temples, resort towns fairly close by.
3. Europe: Berlin: very safe, visa okay for most countries, much cheaper than London or Paris, really nice in August, to do: party all night long, street foods, beer garden, excellent museums, live music etc.
4. North America: many options but visa can be a problem depending on country. Most places will be fairly hot and humid in August, I'd look at Vancouver.
5. Australia/New Zealand: probably too cold in August
6. Some resort Island (Aruba, Maledives, Fiji, Bahamas). Warrants a second look. Typically easy to get to and visa friendly (to support tourism). However it'll be high season in August (summer vacation in the Northern hemisphere) or insanely hot or both.

Comment: -1 for including Berlin as Schengen visas are not “okay” for most of humanity (technically most *countries* might be almost – but not quite – correct but when China, India, Indonesia, Nigeria and the rest of Africa, Pakistan, Bangladesh, or Russia are not included, that's kind of moot). Australia is bad too.